# Sonar-scanner failing with Encoding error

Tags: c++, sonarqube

i am trying to analyse c and c++ based code .I used CppCheck to create a xml file from source code and now, I am running sonar -scanner on same.

my analysis is failing with error:

```
 WARN: Invalid character encountered in 

 [..]/blvm_errors.h at line 29 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
```

Similar to this there are multiple files and errors where I an seeing such warnings.
Any one can help me with same.

Comment: With "Sonar-scanner" do you mean [SonarCube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)?

Comment: yes it's sonarCube.

Answer (score 0):

The errormessage already tells you what to do, set `sonar.sourceEncoding` to the right value.